# what is the use of pigeon-hole principle in proving $\inf_{n,m \in \mathbb{N}}|n-2m\pi|=0$?

Tags: proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

The resource of the proof is : http://mypage.concordia.ca/mathstat/pgora/m364/Density.pdf

The proof used the pigeon-hole principle for infinite cases which was strange.

The proof is:

Denote by $<x>=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$ the fractional part of the real number $x$, which is a number in $[0,1)$. Then I claim that

$\forall \epsilon >0$, $ \exists n_{0},m_{0} \in \mathbb{N} $: $|n_{0}-2 \pi m_{0}|< \epsilon$.

Once this is proved, the lemma also will follow from the properties of inf. To prove
the claim consider all the numbers $<2 \pi a>, a \in \mathbb{N}:$they all belong to $[0,1)$ and
since they are infinitely many, by the Pigeonhole principle there are two (distinct!) $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ which are less than $\epsilon$ apart from each other:

$\epsilon > |<2 \pi a>-<2 \pi b>|=|2 \pi (a-b)- \lfloor 2 \pi a \rfloor + \lfloor 2 \pi b \rfloor|$

We can assume $a<b$ (if not, just rename the numbers) and hence we have the claim
with $n_{0}=\lfloor 2 \pi a \rfloor - \lfloor 2 \pi b \rfloor$ and $m=b-a$.

Comment: It is enough to prove the $\epsilon$ statement, for $\epsilon=1/K$ for positive $K\in\mathbb{Z}$. Divide the interval in equal length intervals of size $1/K$. These are the holes. The pigeons are the values of $\langle 2\pi a\rangle$

Comment: There is a more general result, called [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem). Check the proof in the article.

Comment: Restating what's already in an answer and comments: From "infinitely many" think "more than any finite number", then choose that finite number to be $\lceil 1/\epsilon \rceil$, and you no longer need to deal with infinities.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
Take any $k$ positive integers,
say $a_1,\dots, a_k$.
In order for the result to be false,
all the open balls $B_{\epsilon/2}(<2\pi a_i>)$ must be pairwise disjoint.
However, since $k$ is arbitrary,
and all $<2\pi a_i>$ must lie within $[0,1)$,
we can choose $k$ large enough so that
there must be some overlap between some distinct open balls.
This is where pigeonhole principle is used.
I'll leave the formal details to you.